# Shimano shifter not working

Tags: shimano, shifter, shifting

I’ve got a Shimano Sora shifter and it’s stoped shifting all together on the rear mech recently.

I thought it was the cables so I changed it today and still no joy. I’ve also cleaned it out with WD40 but still not catching.

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You’ll need a little more than WD-40, but should be able to loosen up the ratcheting mechanism. Peel back the rubber, unscrew the plastic guard plate, and now you can look at the bolt that contains the rotary mechanisms. Usually what happens is a piece of wire frays off the cable and wraps around the bolt. Look carefully and use a thin knife or something to fish it out.

Answer (score 0):

The ratchet ring/teeth inside the mech might be stripped. 
I only use Campagnolo shifters, so I don't know how serviceable the specific Shimano Shifter/Brifters you have are, but you could look for something like

on Youtube that applies to your specific model number. I stripped the ratchets in a Campy Record brifter once because the shift cable frayed and a couple strands got mixed up in the ratchet assembly. 
 Worst case scenario you could probably find a new shifter on ebay.

Comment: Can you get spares for Shimano shifters somewhere?